# Tableview getting reloaded when app is going to background when app scrolled till end

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I am using swift 3.0. If we scroll tableview to the end and switch app to the background, tableview is getting reloaded till second last row. Is there any way to avoid this behaviour of tableview?

It doesn't call delegate methods if last cell is not visible.

I tried fetching contentOffset of tableview when going to background and resetting it when coming back. It works perfect except it has reloading effect which I am not able to avoid.

I also tried `sleep(1)`. It shows splash sreen for 1 second every time we come to foreground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution. App needs to support both landscape and portrait modes, so this is the iOS behaviour. If I lock app to landscape mode, its working fine but doesn't support adaptability feature.